# elementFromPoint relative to parent not document

Tags: jquery, html

I got two layers (divs) - both positioned absolutely at 0,0 on relative background. One has lower z-index than other. On both there are some other divs. Would like to be able to act on top layer (so `pointer-events:none;` does not apply), but to show tooltips to elements on bottom layer (with lower z-index). As far as I know, there is a `elementFromPoint()` function that can get element from coordinates. But this only applies to `document`. Is there any function that would do the same but with children of selected node? In other words. Would like to know what object do I have on given coordinates of given layer, that is not top-most without losing events bind to top-most one.